# Grabbing a image from an image map

Tags: android

I just want to know how to basically get image from a image map like in minecraft when it was in 1.2.5.

Image Map:

[image]

So as you can see the image map has a lot of images within... what I want is to grab a 16x16px  from the image map and use it as a drawable for what I'm doing.

Hopefully I was able to explain this well. Sorry for the bad english and stuff I just really don't know what it's called.

Comment: Are there always the exact same number of squares(vertically and horizontally) and are they all always 16x16px ?

Comment: @GeorgiAngelov: Yes they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Bitmap.createBitmap()` method.  You'll be able specify the number of pixels you want to extract and and starting point.  So just loop over the original bitmap adding 16px for the next starting coordinate.

Link : [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap), int, int, int, int)